# Entire registry backup

Tags: windows, backup, windows-registry

How do I create a backup of the **entire** Windows registry
(Windows 7 in my case),
*in a format so that it can be easily restored?*

I want to install a fresh copy of Windows, and I want to back up
the configurations of my installed software on other drives.

Comment: In general, this is a bad idea. The registry is constantly changing. Rolling back to a previous version of the registry is likely to break things. A better solution is to backup just the bits of the registry that you care about. Using restore points may or may not work too depending on what your end goal is.

Comment: I've had good results with [ERUNT](http://www.larshederer.homepage.t-online.de/erunt).

Answer (score 3):

Warning: Floating values exist and this could be a bad idea, but since you asked:

> Start
> type 'regedit'
> Right click the branch you want, click "Export"

It works for Keys and Hkeys.  The reverse is "Import".  But do some research first to figure it out... i.e. The link I gave you.  That was the first result when I google'd your Title.

[Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4230-registry-backup-restore.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) from Piriform to backup the registry before cleaning it. Though I no longer clean my registry, CCleaner still gives the option to do so. If you were to initiate a registry cleaning it would pop up the option to back up. Do so, then cancel the cleaning. You can then restore from that backup at a later date.

See also [CCleaner FAQ: How do I restore registry backups?](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/faq/using/how-do-i-restore-registry-backups)

Comment: Doesn't that only backup the ones your are deleting during the "clean"?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create a backup of the **entire** Windows registry?

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `regedit`,
press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then right-click *Computer* and choose *Export*.
Save the `.reg` file to a place that you remember if and when you need
it.

[image: Right-click 'Computer' and choose 'Export'.]

Making a backup of the entire registry after a fresh installation is a
great idea, but beware that it's going to be a *BIG* file.
In my case, I backed up the entire registry on Windows 10, build
version 22H2.
The exported file is about 507 MB in size.

*Never ever consider restoring this 507 MB file in its entirety!*
The way to use this backup is to copy-paste small chunks from it,
*or* to just look inside it for comparison with parts in
your current installation of Windows.
This is particularly useful if you manipulated the registry, and
are now worried that you broke it, or just wonder what the registry
looked like before you started to make changes to it.

The 507 MB file is going to be awkward to handle.
Consider it to be a safety backup that you hopefully will never need.

#### Back up the *part* of the registry you intend to manipulate

In addition to backing up the *entire* registry, before you
make any changes, *also* backup just the narrow part of the registry
where you intend to make changes.

For example, I'm about to add some keys to
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft`.
Hence, I made a backup of exactly that registry key.
The resulting registry file is merely 4 kB.
This is of course much easier to look inside and/or copy-paste from
than a 507 MB registry file that covers the *whole* registry.
<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
Exporting the *entire* registry from a computer with a *non-fresh*
installation, with the intention to run this `.reg` file
(or parts of it) on a *fresh* installation of Windows, is the exact
opposite of how you should use a backup of the registry.
This might explain the negative feedback (downvotes) your question has
received.